# How to get matrix full of random numbers to exclude negative numbers?

Tags: r

Just a quick question here: I created a matrix full of random numbers in which each row sums to 100. However, it includes negative numbers. I would like it so that the matrix only includes positive numbers between 0 and 100 in each row.

I have tried the following function:

```
matrix <- t(replicate(30,{x <- runif(3, 0, 50); y <- c(x, 100 - sum(x)); sample(y/sum(y) * 100)}))
```

I tried changing the min, which should be equal to 0 right now (and the max is 50), but that didn't work. What am I missing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps a quibble or perhaps a point, but if a bunch of numbers sum to 100, then they aren't random. They do have a constraint.In particular, if your row size is N and you give me the first (N-1) numbers, I can 'predict' the Nth number.

Comment: @Aginensky true!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just scale first then `sample`.

```
mat <- t(replicate(30, {
  x <- runif(4, 0, 50)
  sample(x/sum(x) * 100)
  }))

any(mat < 0)
#[1] FALSE

all(rowSums(mat) == 100)
#[1] TRUE
```

I have changed the matrix name to `mat` because `matrix` is the name of a base R function.

Comment: Thank you, Rui Barradas. After comparing my function's output to yours, I think the problem (or at least part of the problem) was that I was using sample(y/sum(y)) instead of sample(x/sum(x)). I tried your solution and it worked. Thanks again!